# NIC not starting after rebooting Ubuntu server 18.04.3

Tags: networking, 18.04, wired

When first starting the system, the network interface works well, but after rebooting the system it doesn't come up and it's not even detected on `ifconfig -a`.

Any clue on what this could be?

Answer (score 0):

After changing some settings on CMOS of the computer NIC is working again.
Don't know why it showed up on the first time that I booted the computer with Ubuntu 18.04.